# SQL aggregate of calculated field

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005 I have a query that gets child records from bundles that has a calculated field for quantity.  The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT  TblB_1.fooID, 
    TblC.quantity * (TblA.quantity) AS Quantity, 
    TblB_1.name AS Name
    FROM    TblB AS TblB_1 INNER JOIN
              TblC ON TblB_1.fooID = TblC.fooID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              TblB INNER JOIN
                TblA ON TblB.fooID = TblA.fooID ON TblC.parentfooID = TblB.fooID
    WHERE   (TblB.isBundle = 1) AND (TblA.isDeleted = 0)
```

I need to be able to group by id and get a SUM of the quantity field.  I've tried wrapping the quantity line with sum like this:

```
SUM(TblC.quantity * (TblA.quantity)) AS Quantity,
```

Then adding

```
GROUP BY TblB_1.fooID
```

after the WHERE clause, but that results in a "TblB_1.name is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error.

I also tried to get my head around using a subquery for this task, but I was not able to make that work either, nor could I find an example here or on the Web that I have been able to adapt.  Thanks - Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you need to group by all the non aggregate fields. Like so

```
SELECT  TblB_1.fooID, 
    SUM(TblC.quantity * (TblA.quantity)) AS Quantity, 
    TblB_1.name AS Name
FROM    TblB AS TblB_1 INNER JOIN
          TblC ON TblB_1.fooID = TblC.fooID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          TblB INNER JOIN
            TblA ON TblB.fooID = TblA.fooID ON TblC.parentfooID = TblB.fooID
WHERE   (TblB.isBundle = 1) AND (TblA.isDeleted = 0)
GROUP BY TblB_1.fooID, TblB_1.name
```

Comment: This did the trick - although it seems odd that I have to GROUP BY all the fields in my result set to get it to work.  Thanks